# Symfony: How can i use Remote procedure call (RPC) with Messenger?

Tags: rabbitmq, symfony4, rpc, symfony-messenger

I'm trying to do RPC with Symfony Messenger but I get stuck.
Looking at the Messenger component it looks like the implementation has not been added:

https://github.com/webnet-fr/symfony/branches/all
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/34337/commits/06a5a434ce6e5349a33e81c97d83c8b4392603cd

But, I tell myself, if it hasn't been added it's because there should be a way for it to work but ... I can't find it.
Could someone please confirm if it is possible to do RPC with Messenger? if you have any documentation, I am a taker and I will thank you.

Comment: This blog might be useful for you: https://vria.eu/delve_into_the_heart_of_the_symfony_messenger/

Comment: Thank's. But the problem with this blog is the ReplyStamp. in symfony 4.4 this stump doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is to user the HttpClient component (asynchronous mode) and stream the responses for full asynchronous.